# How to have common query in django?

Tags: django

I have a "bell" icon on nav bar - which shows notification for each user. As of now, all the nav bars are made common layouts and included into blocks of each page in django.

Now the problem is when ever I go to a screen, it needs to make query on all notification model to display the notifications. And I have 24 pages, which means notification needs to be fetched for 24 times.

How to make this effciently, so that **I just query once and show notification on each page when user visits there**.

Please guide, I don't know what code to show. If you need any code please mention in the comments.

Comment: Add a comment if you face some troubles after trying the answer

Answer (score 0):

**To use a same variable value on many templates in Django, you can use context processor**

**Create a context_processors.py** file in your app.
And write your logic inside it.

```
from app.models import Notifications

def notifications_count(request) -> dict:
    count = Notifications.objects.count()
    return dict(notifications_count=count)
```

**Add it to Django context_processors in the TEMPLATES variable (settings file)**

```
'context_processors': [
# ...
'app_name.context_processors.notifications_count',
]
```

**At the end in your template file**

```
{{ notifications_count }}
```

You have this value in all your templates files.

Comment: Yes am aware of context_processors, but the thing is that it doesnt stop making new queries on each page refresh or new page navigation ! My question is how to just make one query at and display on all page instead of fetching on each navigation !

Comment: You are right but how do you retrieve the most up to date value without make a query to the database ?

Comment: No idea, thats why posted on stackoverflow ! I think caching would be useful on this scenario ! But not sure

Comment: Not so good because you need to update the value too. Anyways, you can try with `redis`

Comment: why its not good ?

Comment: Because the value must be updated many time i think

Comment: I again had an problem with context_processor ! its just gives error as ```'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable``` when there is no one logged in